# cURL code not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying this tutorial on this page: [Tictail External App Tutorial](https://tictail.com/developers/documentation/authentication/#External_Apps).
Based on this tutorial, one should make a curl call as shown below:

```
$ curl 'https://tictail.com/oauth/token' \
    -d 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
    -d 'client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -d 'code=CODE' \
    -d 'grant_type=authorization_code'
```

To my knowledge, the above curl script could be rewritten in PHP as shown below:

```
$url = "https://tictail.com/oauth/token";
$url .= "?client_id=" . TT_CLIENT_ID;
$url .= "&client_secret=" . TT_CLIENT_SECRET;
$url .= "&code=" . MY_CODE;
$url .= "&grant_type=authorization_code";

$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    var_dump($result);  //This gives: string(87) "405: Method Not Allowed" making me think that something wrong with my code. Could someone please confirm?
```

Sorry I am new to cURL. Thanks.

Comment: Try to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you have to curl your data as `POST`, you cant have it in your url. Add this to your code:

```
$data  = "client_id=" . TT_CLIENT_ID;
$data .= "&client_secret=" . TT_CLIENT_SECRET;
$data .= "&code=" . MY_CODE;
$data .= "&grant_type=authorization_code";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: And if the URL don't respond for POST method? Of course you can have params in the url but it looks to me like a SSL issue.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: I dont think so. He needs to add post code there. But its true, `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` should be there; i didnt see `https` in the url...